# .NET HttpRequestMessage : possible to add header with blank value?

Tags: .net, header, http-headers, request-headers

Is it possible to add a header with value = blank/missing ?

```
HttpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("header-name", string.Empty);

System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=The format of value '' is invalid.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)
       at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)
       at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)
       at
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send a crazy header without value, use `TryAddWithoutValidation()` method, here an example:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://kiewic.com");
var result = request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", string.Empty);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

And cross fingers so the server likes the request.

Answer (score 1):

That would be no. It goes against the [HTTP protocol standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

> #### 4.2 Message Headers
>
> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value.

Comment: Umm... [A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be given with an EMPTY value.](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an empty instance of HttpHeaders in one of the following ways:

```
var headers = new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders;
var headers = new HttpResponseMessage().Headers;
var headers = new HttpRequestMessage().Headers;
You could also make your own class that extends HttpHeaders and use that.
```